# How can I give the video input to PoseNet using TensorFlow.js without a HTML page?

Tags: javascript, tensorflow, tensorflow.js

I am working on https://github.com/tensorflow/tfjs-models/tree/master/posenet  which works on real time .My aim is to save the extracted keypoints from a prerecorded video to a .json file. So is there a way i can give the video input directly to the camera.js without HTML  so that i can run camera.js directly from cmd like   node camera.js.Can anyone tell me how this can be done.? Currently i am able to extract the keypoints for the poses from a prerecorded video and  display using console.

Answer (score 0):

Are you still working on this Swati?  I think this could all be done easier in the browser. Posenet gets it's information from a canvas and it should be fairly easy to load a pre-recorded video onto a canvas.